# Converting any Type to String in Rust

Tags: string, rust, type-conversion

I am new to Rust and often use external crates in my small projects. Sometimes I want to have the corresponding output as a string instead of the returned type or parse it otherwise to modify certain parts of the return.
For example i was using the crate [notify](https://crates.io/crates/notify) and i was getting the paths of the changed files returned as an "event"-type.
This is the Example Code:

```
extern crate notify;
use notify::{RecommendedWatcher, Watcher, RecursiveMode};
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;
use std::time::Duration;

fn watch() -> notify::Result<()> {
    // Create a channel to receive the events.
    let (tx, rx) = channel();

    // Automatically select the best implementation for your platform.
    // You can also access each implementation directly e.g. INotifyWatcher.
    let mut watcher: RecommendedWatcher = try!(Watcher::new(tx, Duration::from_secs(2)));

    // Add a path to be watched. All files and directories at that path and
    // below will be monitored for changes.
    try!(watcher.watch("/home/test/notify", RecursiveMode::Recursive));

    // This is a simple loop, but you may want to use more complex logic here,
    // for example to handle I/O.
    loop {
        match rx.recv() {
            Ok(event) => println!("{:?}", event),
            Err(e) => println!("watch error: {:?}", e),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    if let Err(e) = watch() {
        println!("error: {:?}", e)
    }
}
```

The crate has no display method implemented. How can I convert this event type into a string?
Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say `convert this event type into a string` you actually mean get the path of the file that is the source of the event?

Comment: The event consists of the executed action, e.g. WRITE, DELETE, etc. and the path. 
I have now found out that I can convert the path individually into a string with the Raw API. However, I cannot convert the respective operation (op in the Raw API).
But since I only want to output WRITE operations, for example, I need this, don't I?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want to do. This seems like an XY problem: why do you need to convert an event (presumably [`notify::RawEvent`](https://docs.rs/notify/4.0.16/notify/struct.RawEvent.html)?) to a string? Surely it would be better to keep it as a `RawEvent`, and use its public fields to determine what kind of event it is?

Comment: Aside: You seem to be copying from a really old tutorial or something; the `try!` macro has been superseded by the `?` operator since 1.13 (and will issue a deprecation warning since 1.39).

Comment: I was thinking of converting the event type to a string to use with an if clause. You're probably right that it would be better to leave it as a RawEvent, but even then I don't see how I could use that in an If clause.
Maybe there is this possibility, but as I am generally still a beginner in programming, the Rust documentation of the different crates sometimes seems a bit complicated to me.

Comment: @devyan You can check equality against `notify::op::Op`: `if event.op == Op::CHMOD { ... }`

Comment: You don't seem to need the raw event API, either; `if let DebouncedEvent::Write(path) = event { ... }` should work. Perhaps you should read the sections of the book about [enums and pattern matching](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-00-enums.html).

Comment: I with the Raw API I have now managed it. Many thanks for your help!
Unfortunately, I can't isolate op from the event with the normal API.
I will read the chapter, thank you!

Comment: @trentcl That's just a copy/paste of the example code from the [notify](https://crates.io/crates/notify) crate. Seems they haven't bothered to update it to more recent syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@devyan I had the same problem for a while. Here is what worked.

```
let (tx, rx) = channel();

// Create a watcher object, delivering debounced events.
// The notification back-end is selected based on the platform.
let mut watcher = watcher(tx, Duration::from_secs(10)).unwrap();

// Add a path to be watched. All files and directories at that path and
// below will be monitored for changes.
watcher.watch(dir, RecursiveMode::Recursive).unwrap();

loop {
    match rx.recv() {
        Ok(event) => {
            //Your debounced events...
            println!("{:?}", event);
            match event {
                DebouncedEvent::Write(filepath_buf) => { 
                    //Your file path...
                    println!("{:?}", filepath_buf.as_path())
                }
                _ => {}
            }
        }
        Err(e) => println!("watch error: {:?}", e),
    }
}
```